# IPhone app as a digital wallet. Will Account Topup be considered as in-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am creating a iPhone app which will act as a digital wallet. I can pay my bill at a restaurant using this app.

So can I implement payment gateway services in app to Add money to my account?

Will it interfere with in-App purchase?

Comment: What do you mean "Will it interfere with in-App purchase?" Do you mean will Apple reject this?

Comment: Yes, will apple reject this ?